# Relate between two tables in model Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I have a question, How i can relate two table in model function?
I want to relate between table stores and orders but i can't relate them..
can you help me please?

this is my stores table
[image]

and this is my orders table
[image]

**Update**
This is my code

```html
public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class,'id','store_id');
    }
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: @madalinivascu look my update

Comment: please paste the errors

Comment: @DhavalChheda actually dont give me error, but give me nothing(null)

Comment: remove the 'id' from the belongsTo and check

Comment: @DhavalChheda same result, give me null